# What knowledge are needed if I want to understand kalman filters

Tags: filter, kalman-filter

I am a programmer , and I want to use kalman-filters in work, but I got stuck on it because these formulas are difficult to understand, can you tell me what base knowledge are needed if I want to understand kalman filters? By the way, I have learned some base data structures and algorthm, but my math is not very good.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you have in mind by "understand". If you want to understand how to derive a filter, tweak it and apply to a complex task you need a good matrix algebra and algorithms' grip on top of a very good understanding of mathematical modeling which means differential equations.

If you want to understand how already written Kalman algorithm works, and that, it is only a more "flexible/adaptive" version of low pass filter, you need only some good book and do not go deep into equations. One of the best books I can recommend is by [Kim Phil](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Kalman-Filter-Beginners-MATLAB-Examples/dp/1463648359)

If you want to have more specific answer, you probably need to ask more specific question as @hd1 already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What does your data look like? It's entirely possible the [Kalman filter](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/kalman/media/pdf/Kalman1960.pdf) is not the one you need. I'd read the abstract and maybe some of the references. At that point, if you have further questions, post specific questions here.